# re.split() vs str.split() in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

I have come across this function that is supposed to tokenize a given sentence

```
def basic_tokenizer(sentence):
    words = []
    for space_separated_fragment in sentence.strip().split():
        words.extend(re.split(" ", space_separated_fragment))
    return [w for w in words if w]
```

as i see it sentence.strip().split() should have been enough but then re.split() is used and then even [w for w in words if w] in the return

I wanted to know what could be the reason for this? An example that comes out different through all three would be appreciated

Comment: If it was `re.split(" ")` that was doing the actual splitting, or if the for loop were over `.split(" ")` instead of just `.split()`, then `[w for w in words if w]` would make sense, because there could be empty strings in `words`. Just for future reference.

Comment: @NathanVērzemnieks multiple consecutive spaces are all treated as one space by str.split()

Comment: Yes, if you split with no argument - but not if you split on just " ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole function can be shortened to:

```
def basic_tokenizer(sentence):
    return sentence.split()
```

**Why:**

- `sentence.strip().split()` already strips off the end spaces, and splits on whitesapces, there is no point iterating over the resulting list and `extend`-ing the `words` list by *again* splitting on spaces (`words.extend(re.split(" ", space_separated_fragment))`)
- Moreover, in `[w for w in words if w]` the `if w` check is redundant too as no falsey element is present (as all are non-empty strings)

Comment: The second use of spilt is completely redundant, though - `space_separated_fragment` is guaranteed not to have any whitespace in it, because it's the result of `sentence().strip().split()`.

Comment: This is from the starter code for assignment 4 provided by Stanford in cs224n. Might i suggest you suspected your answer once and confirmed if you still think re.split() usage is redundant completely?

Comment: also, why "return [w for w in words if w]". "return words" seems like the thing to do

Comment: There's no need to use `strip()` - it's totally redundant when used with `split()` (i.e. with no arguments).

Comment: @ekhumoro Yeah. Edited.

Comment: no need for a function definition, just `basic_tokenizer = str.split`